# Duplication check of Email id and Phone number in Firebase database using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm completely new to firebase. I'm creating a basic contact form for my application and connected that to the firebase database. I don't have any authentication for my application. . I have set all the rules to `True` . I want to prevent duplication, if there exists phone number and email in database I want to display an error message.

Below is my code which I have tried

```js
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
// Reference messages collection

// Listen for form submit
document.getElementById('contactform1').addEventListener('submit', submitForm);
// Submit form
function submitForm(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // Get values
  var fname = getInputVal('fname');
  var lname = getInputVal('lname');
  var email = getInputVal('email');
  var phone = getInputVal('phone');
  var skills = getInputVal('skills');
  var jobId = getInputVal('jid');
  var linkedin = getInputVal('linkedin');
  var github = getInputVal('github');
  var location = getInputVal('location');


  // Save message
  saveMessage(fname, lname, email, skills, phone, jobId, linkedin, github, location, );
  // file upload
  var fileButton = document.getElementById("fileButton");
  var file = fileButton.files[0];

  firebase.storage().ref('self/' + file.name).put(file);
  
}
// Function to get get form values
function getInputVal(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id).value;
}

// Save message to firebase
function saveMessage(fname, lname, email, skills, phone, jobId, linkedin, github, location) {
  firebase.database().ref().child('self/data/' + phone).set({
    name: fname + " " + lname,
    email: email,
    phone: phone,
    skills: skills,
    jobId: jobId,
    linkedin: linkedin,
    github: github,
    location: location
  });
}
//snapshot to check the values in database
  firebase.database().ref().child('self/data/' ).on('child_added', snap => {
    var name = snap.child('name').val();
    var email = snap.child('email').val();
    var phone = snap.child('phone').val();
    var skills = snap.child('skills').val();
    var jobId = snap.child('jobId').val();
    var linkedin = snap.child('linkedin').val();
    var github = snap.child('github').val();
    var location = snap.child('location').val();
   
    $('#table_bdy').append('<tr><td>' + name + '</td><td>' + email + '</td><td>' + phone + '</td><td>' + skills + '</td><td>' + jobId + '</td><td>' + location + '</td><td>' + github + '</td><td>' + linkedin + '</td></tr>')

  })
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: Hello @PeterHaddad I want to prevent duplication of email and phone number. If the email and phone number exists in the database i wanna display error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before saving the new values to the database, retrieve the data from the database and check if the email written in the form is the same as an email retrieved from the database. For example:

```
  var newEmail = getInputVal('email');
  firebase.database().ref().child('self/data/' ).on('child_added', snap => {
  var name = snap.child('name').val();
  var email = snap.child('email').val();
  if(newEmail.trim() === email.trim())
  {
     console.log("email already exists in the database");
  }
  else 
  {
    saveMessage(fname, lname, newEmail, skills, phone, jobId, linkedin, github, location);
  }
});
```

---

Try the following:

```
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig); 
 // Reference messages collection 

// Listen for form submit 
document.getElementById('contactform1').addEventListener('submit', submitForm); 
// Submit form 
function submitForm(e) { 
  e.preventDefault(); 
// Get values 
 var fname = getInputVal('fname'); 
 var lname = getInputVal('lname'); 
 var newEmail = getInputVal('email'); 
 var newPhone = getInputVal('phone'); 
 var newskills = getInputVal('skills'); 
 var newjobId = getInputVal('jid'); 
 var newlinkedin = getInputVal('linkedin'); 
 var newgithub = getInputVal('github'); 
 var newlocation = getInputVal('location'); 

saveMessage(fname, lname, newEmail, newskills, newPhone, newjobId, newlinkedin, newgithub, newlocation); 
} 

function saveMessage(fname, lname, newEmail, skills, phone, jobId, linkedin, github, location) { 
 let ref = firebase.database().ref().child('self/data/'); 
  ref.on('value', snap => { 
   if(snap.exists()) 
   { 
     snap.forEach(childSnapshot => { 
     var name = childSnapshot.child('name').val(); 
     var email = childSnapshot.child('email').val(); 
     var phone = childSnapshot.child('phone').val(); 
     var skills = childSnapshot.child('skills').val(); 
     var jobId = childSnapshot.child('jobId').val(); 
     var linkedin = childSnapshot.child('linkedin').val(); 
     var github = childSnapshot.child('github').val(); 
     var location = childSnapshot.child('location').val(); 
     var status = childSnapshot.child('status').val(); 
     console.log(status); 
      if (newEmail.trim() === email.trim()) 
      { //check if email exists 
        console.log("email already exists in the database"); 
      } 
      else 
      { 
         console.log('hello'); 
         firebase.database().ref().child('self/data/' + phone).set({ 
         name: fname + " " + lname, 
         email: email, 
         phone: phone, 
         skills: skills, 
         jobId: jobId, 
         linkedin: linkedin, 
         github: github, 
         location: location 
       }); 
      } 
   }); 
  } 
  else 
  {  
    firebase.database().ref().child('self/data/' + phone).set({ 
    name: fname + " " + lname, 
    email: email, 
    phone: phone, 
    skills: skills, 
    jobId: jobId, 
    linkedin: linkedin, 
    github: github, 
    location: location 
      }); 
    } 
  }); 
 } 

// Function to get get form values 
function getInputVal(id) { 
   return document.getElementById(id).value; 
}
```

First you need to retrieve the values from the form, and then call the method `saveMessage` in the method check if node `self/data` exists, then retrieve the data and check if email already exists in the database.

Comment: How to get the ```newEmail```  value without submitting the form? if i use set time out function i can get the value. How can i fix it out?

Comment: inside your function `function submitForm(e) {` you are calling `saveMessage()` and you are also retrieving the form values. So, instead of immediately calling `saveMessage()` add my code that I gave you in the answer

Comment: It didn't work out. Please have a look at my code https://codepen.io/manojsai/pen/MdpPqW . Actually i'm trying to snap the values on page load

Comment: add the if condition before creating the table, and in your code, you are retrieving the data inside the eventclicklistener function... so when you click submit you are retrieving...

Comment: Can you please edit the snippet. I'm little confused. I tried that too . Now i'm not even able to send the data to database

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193451/discussion-between-sai-and-peter-haddad).